# TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python, json, maps, geojson, choropleth

Im trying to get a choropleth graph and I get this error `TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not builtin_function_or_method`

```py
import requests
import json

df3 = pd.read_csv('potenciar-trabajo-total-titulares-2022-10-01.csv',low_memory=False)

repo_url = 'https://infra.datos.gob.ar/catalog/modernizacion/dataset/7/distribution/7.12/download/provincias.geojson'
ar_regions_geo = requests.get(repo_url).json()


fig = px.choropleth(
    df3,
    locations="id",
    geojson=ar_regions_geo,
    color="titulares")

fig.show()
```

Expecting to get the choropleth graph

Comment: What does the first couple of rows of your csv look like?

Comment: Please format your code properly in a code block. This helps others read your code a lot faster and saves people's time.